# Remove unwanted double queote from the string

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Example file with 3 columns:

```
"Mahavir", "Sachin" is boy" , "Ankita"
"abc"    , "xyz" is girl"   , "uvw"
```

Desired output:

```
"Mahavir" , "Sachin is boy , "Ankita"
"abc"    ,  "xyz is girl   , "uvw"
```

Here I want to remove unwanted double quote which u seeing near sachin and xyz.

Comment: I don't get meaning of "one sided inverted comma". Please add sample data or explain in detail, please.

Comment: sample data is given in example

Comment: This example is very unclear.

Comment: Can you please check now... now its very clearly visible that i want to replace right hand side of inverted comma of second field to backslash

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "," '{gsub(/"( *)$/,"\\\1",$2); print $1","$2","$3}' file
```

Comment: no its not doing anything... its just ommiting same.

Comment: I have one more query...What if i wants to do something like... u can see updated ex[planation